# What is a synonym for a casual hiatus?

Tags: synonyms

An example for contextual purposes:
"Smoking has become part of my routine, a [casual hiatus/break] to my day, if you will, rather than an addiction"

Comment: I don't like it as much as the other answers, but I'd like to add "respite" as a possible alternative, depending on additional context.

Comment: *Casual hiatus* still sounds much better and dramatic to me. Depends on the context, though.

Comment: We're really trying to avoid using this site for "single word requests." If you have a particularly *interesting* problem to solve, all we ask is that you put a bit of effort and research into the question. See: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1654/against-single-word-requests/1737#1737 or http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity

Answer (score 5):

One of these might do the trick:

- Intermission
- Recess
- Breather (not recommended when speaking about smoking)
- Interlude

Comment: Gah! Got the "new answer loaded" message in the middle of clicking "Answer."

Comment: @Gnawme Well, sometimes, that's the way it goes. Once, I wrote out a *really* long answer, got that message, and the answer was essentially mine, but compacted.

Comment: Yeah, and then you watch the other answer get twice as many votes... :-b

Comment: @Gnawme To be true!

Comment: How about replacing the whole answer with 'You beat me to it, Maan by nn nanosecs.'? (only if it's the same thing in the two answers)

Comment: RE "breather": A co-worker of mine always used to refer to time he went out to smoke as a "health break".

Answer (score 4):

The most common word for this is the one you included in your example, "break".

Answer (score 3):

How about *[intermission](http://www.wordnik.com/words/intermission)*? Especially in the sense of "recess at school."

> Smoking has become part of my routine, an intermission to my day, if
>   you will, rather than an addiction.